# Force use of new SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I recently let an ssl certificate expire. I then purchased and installed a new certificate (didn't renew the old one do to the cost of renewing an ev cert vs a new basic cert). Everything works fine, however browsers that have visited the site in the past that still have the original public key cached are receiving the scary "Get me out of here" message that you receive when browsing to a site with a self signed/expired certificate. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Have you checked your new SSL installation against SSLLabs.com? Perhaps your cert chain is incomplete, or there is an issue with the cert. Browsers do not generally cache a cert such that a new, valid cert would be marked as bad.

Comment: check your ssl certificate here https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested I checked the site with ssllabs and it came back that the chain was incomplete. When the cert was provided it came in two peices, a domain.ca-bundle and domain.crt. The cert that nginx was using was domain.ca-bundle. I concatenated the two and that seems to have taken care of it.